# getting the values as 'null' value in LocalStorage.getItem

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular-local-storage

In my application I have to use the Email value coming from login to dashboard component(both are individual components).

So in login component I have stored the values in localstorage by using setItem as'

**login.component.ts**

```
//somecode

if (loggedIn) {
  localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKey.KEY_CoachGender, this.coachProfile.CoachGender);
  localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKey.KEY_Email, this.coachProfile.Email);
}
```

and
**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
let EmailId = localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKey.KEY_Email);
this.hubConnection.invoke("Register", EmailId)
console.log("Connected")
console.log(EmailId)
```

But while I am getting the EmailId from loacal Storage I am getting the null value in console
Can anyone help me how to get the value without getting the nullvalue

Comment: first see if local storage has the email id stored or not already before you are reading it... Move that `console.log(EmailId);` 2 lines up..

Comment: Is `loggedIn === true`? Check if it is being set in your code. Please add a `debugger` before both `setItem` and `getItem`, open dev tools and debug your code.

Comment: Thanks@Nalin Ranjan, I have moved the console and tested even though it is is showing null value. Can you please help me how to get the value(Email) instead of this locals torage method then it will be helpful for me

Comment: add  `console.log('setting email: ', this.coachProfile.Email);` after `localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKey.KEY_Email, this.coachProfile.Email);`
to see if the line gets executed and if you are setting something or null.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem is you don't have considered the asynchronicity, probability you don't wait the logging is done before you insert the result in localStorage